# AWS SES DMARC - Gmail Bounce

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, dmarc

I'm getting inconsistent Bounces from Gmail because of DMARC. Below are 2 examples where one was delivered and the other bounced:

The Domains are different but the DNS, Dmarc, SPF and DKIM are the same.

Does anyone have any advise as to why one would bounce and the other wouldn't?

Just trying to achieve constant delivery. Note: this only occurs with Gmail.

thankyou
Adam

Note: possibly the second one that bounces is from a subdomain. Could that be why?

Comment: It's really hard to answer this question, without knowing the domain names in question.  I would think perhaps one has a DMARC policy set to "none" and the other probably has it set to "reject". You should send an email from both domains to an [Email Authentication Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/) to get a better idea of what's going on.  Or just list the domains, so people can be of more help.